# Can't open command prompt from file menu

Tags: windows-8.1, cmd.exe

I am running Windows 8.1 and in explorer I cant open `cmd` from any folder via file menu. The option is unavailable.

Comment: One option to add command prompt to the menus was an unofficial extra in the PowerToys package?  I dunno if that will work on Win8 or if theres a Win8 equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Explorer, hold down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key and right-click in the blank area in the right-hand pane (i.e. not on a file). The pop-up menu will include "Open command window here".

Added in response to OP request: to make "Open command window here" work without having to press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, you need to edit the registry (you must be an administrator to do this). Delete the value 'Extended' from the following key:-

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd

Once this is done, the right-click menu will include "Open new command window here" (as long as you right-click on a folder). You can make this work for drives as well by deleting 'Extended' from HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cmd.

Comment: that is alright but is there any way I could restore the option in the file menu

Comment: I've added the method for restoring the option to the normal right-click menu to my answer. Hope that's OK.